# Is there a way to export more than 1000 spans/traces from datadog?

Tags: datadog

I want to perform some analysis on spans/traces which have been recorded into datadog. While their UI allows exporting spans, this is limited to 5000 rows. The dataset I wish to analyse has ~ 500k spans so it's not really practical to use their UI for this export. I'd be happy to get the data from their API but I can't find where spans/Traces are retrieved in their API and their UI uses an older version of their API.

Has anyone successfully access spans via the datadog UI or knows of any other system for performing this export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options here:

1. The spans API - https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/spans/
2. It seems like they recently increased the limit of spans exported through the UI to 100K. I couldn't find any announcement or documentation saying that, but I can see that in my workplace's account.